# Metrics server pods are not created on kOps

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I'm using kOps 1.26.3 and Kubernetes 1.26.5, running on AWS. After upgrading with `kops upgrade cluster`, metrics server stopped working.

It is installed using this on cluster manifest:

```yaml
  metricsServer:
    enabled: true
```

Some resources, like the service, are created. But there are no metric-server pods, nor deployments:

```
$ kubectl get service metrics-server -n kube-system
E0523 12:28:33.191542   35151 memcache.go:287] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0523 12:28:33.517819   35151 memcache.go:121] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0523 12:28:33.679998   35151 memcache.go:121] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0523 12:28:33.836750   35151 memcache.go:121] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
metrics-server   ClusterIP   100.69.1.148   <none>        443/TCP   213d
$
$ kubectl get pods -A | grep metrics-server
E0523 12:44:00.464132   36275 memcache.go:287] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0523 12:44:00.780095   36275 memcache.go:121] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0523 12:44:00.942123   36275 memcache.go:121] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
E0523 12:44:01.103146   36275 memcache.go:121] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

Since there are no pods, I don't know where to look for logs. I tried to terminate the instances and let kOps recreate them several times, with the same result.

Comment: you have that error, because there is nod pod managing the request, you could check using "kubectl get apiservices | grep metrics" but I don't know why the pod metrics pod is crashing

Comment: @c4f4t0r: yeah it says the following in the column Available: "False (MissingEndpoints)". Its name is "v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io" and service is "kube-system/metrics-server".